# ASP.NET _ViewStart.cshtml - Getting the Request

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET app. My app has a _ViewStart.cshtml file. That file looks like this:

```
@using MyCompany.MyApp;
@{
  Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

  var p = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["parameter"];
  ViewBag.QSParameter = p;
}
```

When I execute this code, I get the following error:

```
The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context
```

I don't understand. Isn't _ViewStart.cshtml kind of the "shell" for the views? I'm trying to figure out how to globally read a query string parameter and set a value on the ViewBag for each request. I thought this would be the way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve it from `_ViewStart.cshtml`, you can use:

```
ViewBag.QSParameter = Context.Request.Query["parameter"];
```

*Note: Use [`Query`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/288) now (over `QueryString`) in ASP.NET 5*

However, I might ellect to go a different route and take advantage of `IResultFilter`:

```
public class QSParameterFilter : IResultFilter
{
  public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
  {
    var QSParameter = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["parameter"];
    ((Controller)context.Controller).ViewBag.QSParameter = QSParameter;
  }
  public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context) { }
}
```

Then, register it within your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc();
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
  options.Filters.Add(new QSParameterFilter());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should have access to `Request` in your _ViewStart file.

Try this:

```
@using MyCompany.MyApp;
@{
  Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

  var p = Request.QueryString["parameter"];
  ViewBag.QSParameter = p;
}
```

**EDIT: For ASP.NET 5**

I don't have ASP.NET 5 on my machine but have looked at the source code for the framework. It looks like there is a `Context` property on `RazorPage` that returns an `HttpContext`. Alternatively, you can access the `HttpContext` through the `ViewContext`. See below:

```
@{
  Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

  var p = Context.Request.Query["parameter"];
  // or this...
  // var p = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["parameter"];
  ViewBag.QSParameter = p;
}
```

Comment: I did. No luck. I should mention that I'm using ASP.NET 5. I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I assumed MVC 3-5 ... Let me dig some more.

Answer (score 0):

Make the "Build Action = Content" in the file properties. This will solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).