# Accessing HttpContext within _ViewStart

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm trying to access the HttpContext from within _ViewStart.cshtml. When I do I get the error HttpContext doesn't exist in the current context.

Here's the line of code that is causing the error...

```
string thisDomain = HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString().ToLower();
```

The reason I am looking for the domain is that I will load a different layout depending upon the name of the current domain host. The site will be bound to many different domains.

Any ideas on why HttpContext is not visible/accessible within _viewstart.cshtml. I'm sure there's  probably a good reason, but if so, what alternatives do I have for determining the current host/domain?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Bob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET \_ViewStart.cshtml - Getting the Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127261/asp-net-viewstart-cshtml-getting-the-request)