# How to get URL of page in .net Core Partial View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to get the URL of the page inside a partial view without passing it in as part of the model?

Request.Path.Value gets me the URL, but how do we get the Request object?

Answer (score 1):

I found an object called Context from which I can grab it.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127261/asp-net-viewstart-cshtml-getting-the-request) helped

thanks [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59849/peter)